# How can I connect multiple HDD's to one motherboard?

Tags: hard-drive, desktop-computer, storage

As the title says, how can I do that? I have an old pc case with space for 9 3.5" HDD's, and I want to use it as a server for 4k video/picture storage.

The case has a GTX460, and 4 sticks of 2gb ddr3 Ripjaws RAM. Do I need anything better as well? (I will not do editing with this pc, just use it as a data server.)

Comment: No idea why you are telling us the graphic card involved, when all you need to know what port are on the mb, usually sata, and if you have any of those disks.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What motherboard do you have and are the disks SATA?  All you need is enough power (and maybe power splitters) and ports on the motherboard or on an expansion card.  You could also look at a RAID controller.

Comment: To be clear, strictly speaking you dont need any graphics for a fileserver that serves video files. Most NAS's handle this without video output at all.

Comment: *"The case has a GTX460, and 4 sticks of 2gb ddr3 Ripjaws RAM"* -- You seem to conflate a *"case"* with a "motherboard" or "system".  Do you understand the difference between these terms?

Comment: @Bib I wasn't sure if it mattered or not.

Comment: @davidgo The motherboard is a P55A-G55. Yes, the one HDD that I have at the moment is SATA.

Comment: @sawdust I understand the difference, I just said case because that was what was on my mind at that moment, lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/P55AG55/Specification the motherboard you have has 2 sata 3 and 6 sata 2 slots - so ignoring IDE it can handle 8 hard drives.

Conceptually you need to implement 8 power connectors (eg by tapping off your power supply, appropriate length sata cables and you can plug up to 8 hard drives into your system. (There are other ways to do this, but thats the simplest from a hardware POV.

Comment: Thank you for the help! My power supply (I'm not entirely sure which one as the label was damaged) has enough SATA power cables, it's just those SATA cables and HDD's that I need.